# {"readyState":0",status:"0",statusText":error"}

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cordova

I am getting the following error:

> jquery ajax readystate 0 responsetext status 0 statustext error when giving it: url(url ="http://41.230.20.149:8080/WebServiceSuiveur/utilisateurs/login?pseudo="+$('#pseudo').val()+"&motdepasse="+$("#motdepasse").val();), 
>   for real device

Can anyone please explain the problem to me, as I'm quite new to this.

```
 var url =serverPath+"WebServiceSuiveur/utilisateurs/login?pseudo="+$('#pseudo').val()+"&motdepasse="+$("#motdepasse").val();
 $.ajax({
    "url":url,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "JSON",
    timeout: 1000000,                      
    "success": function(data) {

    }, 
    "error": function (error,jqXHR, status, errorThrown) {                    
        alert("erreur "+ JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
        alert(JSON.stringify(error));           
    }
 });
```

help me please

Comment: What error is actually reported?

Comment: i get this error "readystate 0 responsetext status 0 statustext error " in the real device but in emulator device using address local it's work fine

Comment: Use `console.log()` instead of `alert(JSON.stringify())` to look at the error. Serializing errors is not that simple.

Comment: i get this error "readystate 0 responsetext status 0 statustext error "

Comment: If your using `console.log()` without `JSON.stringify()` instead of `alert()` you will see a real error message. What your posting here is some serialized fragments, which do not really help resolving your issue.

Comment: when i delete json.stringify i'have [object object] !!

Comment: That's why I say use `console.log()` and not `alert()` ... `alert()` needs to serialize the message, `console.log()` does not!

Comment: Are you sure your port number is 8080 ?

Comment: yes in the local network this url it's work fine

Comment: Means when you use public IP 41.230.20.149 it is not working?

Comment: yes when i use a public @ Ip ,it is not working

Comment: your 41.230.20.149:8080 means port 8080 is not accessible.In this computer have your install your server whatever you use?

Comment: <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
           connectionTimeout="20000" 
           URIEncoding="UTF-8"
           redirectPort="8443"
           useIPVHosts="true" />

Comment: @RimBejaoui Do you have cordova whitelist plugin installed?

Comment: yes look please : cordova plugin list
cordova-plugin-camera 2.1.1 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-console 1.0.3 "Console"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.2 "Device"
cordova-plugin-dialogs 1.2.1 "Notification"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 2.1.0 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.2.2 "Whitelist"

Comment: Are you facing this issue in browser or on android device >

Comment: in the browser for external network i have this error " ce site est inaccessible" a mis trop de temps à répondre" and in android device for external network i have  ({“readyState”:0“,status:”0“,statusText”:error"})

Comment: Go the same error...

Answer (score -1):

```
success: function(data) {

}, 
error: function (error,jqXHR, status, errorThrown) {                    
    alert("erreur "+ JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
    alert(JSON.stringify(error));           
}
```

Comment: This answer would be better if it explained the difference (removing the quotes).  I had to use a diff tool to spot it.